# add salable quantity column in product in categories section

Tags: magento2, grid, backend, category-products, salable

I want to add salable quantity in the product in categories section in adminside. In below image I want to add salable quantity column instead of QTY and get corresponding values.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php` in you module using preference.

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" />
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Product in category grid
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Product extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var Status
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var Visibility
     */
    private $visibility;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     * @param Visibility|null $visibility
     * @param Status|null $status
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = [],
        Visibility $visibility = null,
        Status $status = null
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->visibility = $visibility ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Visibility::class);
        $this->status = $status ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Status::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('catalog_category_products');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('category');
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        // Set custom filter for in category flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_category') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } elseif (!empty($productIds)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if ($this->getCategory()->getId()) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_category' => 1]);
        }
        $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'visibility'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'status'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'price'
        )->joinField(
            'position',
            'catalog_category_product',
            'position',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            'category_id=' . (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0),
            'left'
        );
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        if ($storeId > 0) {
            $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
        }
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_category',
                [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_category',
                    'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                    'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'visibility',
            [
                'header' => __('Visibility'),
                'index' => 'visibility',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->visibility->getOptionArray(),
                'header_css_class' => 'col-visibility',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-visibility'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
                'header' => __('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->status->getOptionArray()
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            ]
        );
      //Qty Column
        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'qty',
                'renderer' => 
'vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Grid\Column\Renderer\SaleableQty'
            ]
        ); 
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('catalog/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_products');
        if ($products === null) {
            $products = $this->getCategory()->getProductsPosition();
            return array_keys($products);
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

> vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Grid\Column\Renderer\SaleableQty.php

```
<?php
 
namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Grid\Column\Renderer;
 
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
 
class SaleableQty extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    private $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    public function __construct(
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku
    ) {
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    }
 
    /**
     * get category name
     * @param  DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        if($row['type_id'] != "configurable" && $row['type_id'] != "bundle" && $row['type_id'] != "grouped"){
            $sku = $row->getSku();
            $salable = $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku->execute($sku);
            return $salable[0]['qty'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did over ride the Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product.php and did the quantity column. its working fine. But for salable quantity, I couldn't find a way to list in the grid. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you can use the renderer to list the saleable qty in grid please check the edited answer

Comment: The answer you provided is corrected and working fine now. but there is an issue came while opening the catalog->product. The page is showing infinity load and while checking system log, ' Argument 1 passed to Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku::execute() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/SalableQuantity.php on line 70 '.

Comment: I solved the issue. in my ' catalog_product_entity ' table , there is some SKU showing NULL. So I updated by using the ' UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET sku='' WHERE sku IS NULL; ' query and the issue solved
Also, the salable quantity is working fine. Thank you, Mehran for your help

Comment: you’re welcome.

Comment: There is an issue with this. When I add stock quantity column, then the search in salable quantity not working and when searching it throw an error "  The "qty" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again. {"report_id":"bcdd225eff9e49e3b60a04cfe403126de36bb6235c2f763357c0f660372ab7ee","exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0) ". How to fix this?